# XOR bytes in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, format, byte, xor

On trying to xor bytes in python3:

```
import os,binascii
import numpy as np

def xor_byte_hex_strings(a, b) :
    return bytes(x ^ y for x, y in zip(a, b))


number_of_bytes = 2

random_bytes = []

random_bytes_str = binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(number_of_bytes))
random_bytes.append(random_bytes_str)

print(random_bytes_str)
print(bytearray(random_bytes_str))

random_bytes_str = binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(number_of_bytes))
random_bytes.append(random_bytes_str)

resultant = xor_byte_hex_strings(random_bytes[0], random_bytes[1])
print("resultant = ", bytearray(resultant))
print(random_bytes)

resultant = xor_byte_hex_strings(random_bytes[1], resultant)
print(resultant)
```

The result is b'\x03\x03\x0cU' instead of b'13ce.
How do we convert the format from b'\x03\x03\x0cU' to b'13ce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not work with strings and `int`s to make your life easier?

```
import os,binascii

def xor_strings(a, b):
    result = int(a, 16) ^ int(b, 16) # convert to integers and xor them together
    return '{:x}'.format(result)     # convert back to hexadecimal

number_of_bytes = 2
random_bytes = []

# decode() to turn it into a str.
random_bytes_str = binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(number_of_bytes)).decode()
random_bytes.append(random_bytes_str)


random_bytes_str = binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(number_of_bytes)).decode()
random_bytes.append(random_bytes_str)

print(random_bytes)
xored = xor_strings(*random_bytes)
print("resultant = ", xored.encode())

print([random_bytes[1], xored])
resultant = xor_strings(random_bytes[1], xored)
print(resultant.encode()) # encode() will turn it back to bytes if you want bytes
```

**Output:**

```
['4588', '3af9']
resultant =  b'7f71'
['3af9', '7f71']
b'4588'
```

Comment: The hex may not be just 2 bytes, it can be arbitrary number of bytes, hence `int(a, 16) ` will not work later. It can't be stored as string as it would be recalled as bytes as well for other processing.

Comment: `int(a, 16)` converts to [base 16](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) (i.e. hex), so it will work for any number of bytes and the last line in my example shows how to convert to a byte str if you want to i.e. `.encode()`, but know that in both my code and yours you are working with a byte string (ascii) via `b2a_hex`, not bytes.